# Boundedness and norm of a sequence operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces

> Let $s = \{s_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a fixed and bounded sequence of real numbers, i.e. $s \in (\ell^{\infty},\|\cdot\|_{\infty})$.  Consider the operator $T_{s} : \ell^{2} \to \ell^{2}$ defined by
>   $$ 
>     T_{s}(\{a_{n}\}) := \{s_{n}a_{n}\}, \phantom{..} \forall \{a_{n}\} \in \ell^{2}, n \in \mathbb{N}.
> $$
>   Show that $T_{s}$ is a bounded linear operator and find $\|T_{s}\|$.

I am seeking hints or tips. Thank you.

Comment: What are your thoughts? In general, to find the norm of an operator you need to 1) find a fairly sharp-seeming bound on $\|Tx\|$ of the form $\|Tx\|\le M\|x\|$, then 2) either show there is $a$ such that $\|Ta\|=M\|a\|$ or there is a sequence $(a_n)$ such that $\|Ta_n\|/\|a_n\|\to M$.

Comment: Right, but there's no $M$ such that $\|Tx\|\le M\|x\|$ in the first place, so your point is moot. The idea is that the first inequality shows $\|T\|\le M$ And the distinguished element or sequence shows $\|T\|\ge M$.

Comment: @Jason sorry I had misread your comment (I thought your second argument is for an upper bound, but it turns out to be about determining the value). Actually when I was struggling to find the exact value of $\|T_s\|$ I found that my procedure was essentially the same as the second part of your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linearity is quite trivial to show. So we only focus on proving boundedness.

Recalling the definition, we only need to show that for all $x\in\ell^2$ s.t. $\|x\|=1$ ($\ell^2$ norm), there exists $M>0$ s.t. $\|T_s x\|\le M$. Then by your definition of $T$, we have that
$$\|T_s x\|=\|\{s_n x_n\}\|=\left(\sum (s_n x_n)^2\right)^\frac12\le \left(\sum \|s\|^2_{\infty}(x_n)^2\right)^\frac12=\|s\|_{\infty}\left(\sum (x_n)^2\right)^\frac12=\|s\|_{\infty}\cdot 1.$$

---

**EDIT** We can also show that $\|s\|_\infty$ is exactly the value of $\|T_s\|$:

1). if $\|s\|_\infty$ is attained, i.e., exists some $k$ such that $|s_k|=\|s\|_\infty$. Then $x_n:=\chi_{\{k\}}(n)$ obviously satisfy that $\|x\|=1$ and $\|Tx\|=\sqrt {s_k^2}=\|s\|_\infty.$

2). otherwise, $s_n<\|s\|_\infty$ but there exists a subsequence of $s$, say $\{s_{N,k}\}_{k\in\Bbb N}$ s.t. $s_{N(k)}\to \|s\|_\infty$ as $k\to\infty$. Let $\{(x_m)\}\subset\ell^2$ s.t. $(x_m):=\{\chi_{\{N(m)\}}(n)\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$, then 
$$\|T_sx_m\|=\sqrt {s^2_{N(m)}}\to\|s\|_\infty,\quad\text{as}\,\, m\to\infty.$$
Either case, we have that
$$\|T_s\|:=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|T_sx\|\ge \|s\|_\infty.$$
But $\|s\|_\infty$ as previously illustrated is also an upper bound for $\|T_s\|$, it follows that $\|T_s\|= \|s\|_\infty$.

Comment: And what is $\|T\|$?

Comment: No I mean what is its operator norm?

Comment: @Jason ok. I worked out that it is $\|s\|_\infty$. Gonna expand on it soon.

Comment: The answer should be $\|s\|_\infty$. You forgot to take square roots in your norm.

Comment: @Jason. Oops. gonna fix it soon. Thanks for the catch

Comment: What is the meaning of this $\chi_{\{k\}}(n)$ notation?

Comment: @clocktower it's called characteristic function. In this particular setting, it means the stuff $=1$ if $n=k$, and $=0$ otherwise.

Comment: @Vim This would be similar to Kroenecker delta?

Comment: @clocktower well, to some extent maybe. But they are not the same thing. You better Google them for more thorough information.

Comment: @clocktower you are welcome.